# GUI based debugger for Ruby?

Tags: ruby, debugging

Is there any GUI based debugger for Ruby? Just a debugger. I do not want a full IDE like NetBeans because they tend to get your project dirty with extra files.

thanks!

Comment: I would <del>give a kidney</del> pay cash money for a GUI debugger that works for Ruby and Rails as well as Chrome's Developer Tools work for Javascript. It's almost enough to tip my language preference. And I second the OP's dislike for full IDEs. Vim is my editor - my debugger should be separate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In netbeans you can tell it to put the netbeans project files in a separate directory or you can easily ignore the nbproject directory with your project's vcs.  Netbeans has by far the best integrated debugging I have seen and there are many other great reasons to give it a try.  Don't worry about netbeans using a project folder.  I highly doubt you'll be able to find a better free GUI debugger.

If the code completion stuff gets in your way with netbeans it is easy to turn off and only request code completion when you want it (ctrl+space).  That was my biggest gripe with netbeans.

Answer (score 7):

Check out [Mr. Guid](http://mr-guid.rubyforge.org/), which uses GTK+ and is cross-platform.

Comment: In case anyone runs into any issues, You'll need the ruby-gnome2  for this to work. 

http://ruby-gnome2.sourceforge.jp/hiki.cgi?Install+Guide

The documentation is a little unclear on how to use it (at least for usual Rails server or Rails console debugging.

Comment: Mr. Guid seems very outdated. Is there a other (newer) GUI based Ruby debugger out there?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it in about a year, but I liked [Arachno Ruby](http://www.ruby-ide.com/ruby/ruby_ide_and_ruby_editor.php)

Comment: I guess this is the new URL http://freshmeat.sourceforge.net/projects/arachnoruby

Comment: It had to kill it because ruby hacked the internals to often and the core team didn't want to support special (fast) debugging hooks. Now all this years later they  still failed ot come up with a good  debugger :-(